# Bootstrap 4 making it fixed width (making it non responsive)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello I'm trying to fix the width to 900px of the Bootstrap page but I can't it's still responsive.

Methods I tried is setting

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and I also tried creating _custom.scss and compiling it with

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
        xs: 895px,
        sm: 896px,
        md: 897px,
        lg: 898px,
        xl: 899px
);
```

or

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
        xl: 899px
);
```

no luck for any of them

Comment: fixing width of which element. container?

Answer (score -1):

```
.container {
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

And wrap all of your rows with

```
<div class="container"></div>
```